# Is it OK to remove field values or revisions by deleting individual lines from the field table in the database?

Tags: 7, entities, database, nodes

I have been testing my site (with revisions enabled) for several days now and I have noticed that my field related database tables are filling up with revision info.  Can I simply delete these line items from the field table or are there other entries that I need to be aware of?

Comment: I think this question is a dup if anyone wants to search.  Manually deleting things, especially revision info, can cause serious problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to Use the [Node Revision Delete](http://drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete) module to delete and manage your revisions.

> The Node Revision Delete module allows you to manage the revisions of the Node according to your choice. It helps you to keep the specific number of revisions for the node. This module provides you the flexibility for applying the revision delete for the specific content type and run it on the specific time. You can manage your settings from the Node Revision Delete Administration Page.